# How does a mass spectrometer treat ions?

Tags: analytical-chemistry, mass-spectrometry

I always thought that in a mass spectrometer all the ionized fragments were going in the quadrupole at the same time, and then this quadrupole was sorting them by ratio.

But last week I learn that a quadrupole mass spectrometer does not work like that, it apparently works by ratio range letting only specific ion enter the quadrupole first and then continuing for others range

I learn that you can even specify a specific mass/charge ratio in the programs for the MS to analyze more these specific ones.

How exactly does it work?

Comment: Can you Google "quadrupole mass spectrometer"?

Answer (score 1):

A quadrupole is a bundle of four parallel metallic bars or rods, fastened horizontally. They must be neighbors, but they must not teach one another. I will call N the highest of all (like North), S the lowest of all  (like South), and E and W the two rods in the middle E at right and W at left. 
The whole is in a vacuum. The ions to analyze are sent in the direction of the central axis, Suppose that the two bars E and W are charged minus in the beginning, and the two bars N and S are charged plus. The bundle of ions entering the quadrupole are attracted by the bars E and W. Their trajectory is deviated to the left or to the right. But they will not touch these bars, because the sens of the charges suddenly changes. Before the ions have touched the W or E plates, these plates have been quickly transformed and are positive, and the bars N and S become negative. The trajectories of the ions is deviated in the direction North or South. But here again, the ions can not touch the N and S electrodes, because the polarity changes once again, repelling the trajectories in the E and W direction. If you choose your frequency with care, the ions having a certain mass follow a helicoidal trajectory and get out of the quadrupole without having been intercepted. The lighter ions touch the bar and are eliminated in the very beginning of the bundle. The heavy ions have a helicoidal trajectory that opens out and touch one of the bars before getting out of the quadrupole.

It means that a quadrupole is a device for selecting ions of a certain ratio m/z. All the other ones are eliminated. This choice is dependent on the choice of the frequency.